# ¿Cómo puedo saber el tiempo activo de la web?

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo puedo saber en JavaScript cuánto tiempo lleva una página que NO está enfocada, pero sí abierta? Osea, que la tiene abierta pero está navegando en otras, ¿cómo puedo saber hace cuánto tiempo que no enfoca la mía?

Comment: Puede ser una pregunta interesante, solo `Javascript` o también puede emplear `Jquery` ?

Comment: Deberías concretar un poco cuál es el objetivo: ¿Quieres que realice alguna actividad pasado X tiempo (incluso estando fuera de foco)?¿Quieres que muestre un mensaje en plan "te odio! me has ignorado por X tiempo!"? Tal y como está ahora la pregunta es interesante, pero parece un poco ampia

Comment: Alvaro es para varias cosas por eso

Answer (score 9):

Esto lo puedes conseguir con la [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/). Con esa API puedes obtener información sobre si la página está visible/enfocada o no. Entonces lo que harías sería:

1. Crear un controlador del evento de cambio de visibilidad
2. Si la página ha perdido visibilidad/foco:

   1. Guardar la hora actual en una variable
3. Si la página ha ganado visibilidad/foco:

   1. Leer la hora actual
   2. Comparar con la hora guardada
   3. Realizar acciones acorde a los valores

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de cómo sería basado en la demo que hay en la [página de MDN para la API de la Visibilidad de Página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API):

```js
// Especificar el nombre de la propiedad hidden y del evento de cambio para la visibilidad
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 y Firefox 18 
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

var horaEscondida = "";
var horaActual = "";

// Si la pagina se esconde, guarda la hora
// Si la pagina se muestra, compara horas
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    horaEscondida = Date.now();
  } else {
    var horaActual = Date.now();
    console.log("Me escondiste durante " + Math.floor((horaActual - horaEscondida) / 1000) + " segundos");
  }
}

// Muestra mensaje en la consola si el navegador no soporta addEventListener o la Page Visibility API
if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || typeof document[hidden] === "undefined") {
  console.log("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
} else {
  // Controlador de cambios de visibilidad en la pagina   
  document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);
}
```

Un motivo para usar esta API es que los eventos `focus` y `blur` en la ventana pueden fallar y/o dar falsos positivos. Por ejemplo: Si el usuario abre la consola de JS se considerará que la ventana perdió foco incluso cuando el usuario sigue en ella (aunque dependiendo de lo que quieras, eso te puede valer).

Además, no todos los navegadores los soportan; por ejemplo: en iPad/iPhone están los eventos `pageShow`/`pageHide` en lugar de `focus` y `blur` para la página. Lo que podría llevar a algunos problemas en dispositivos móviles.

Una opción sería extender el código de arriba para usar Page Visibility y si no funciona o no está disponible, pasar a la solución de `focus`/`blur`.

Comment: Me gusta. Una solución bastante más completa

Answer (score 4):

Es una pregunta interesante como ya tienes una respuesta en `Javascript` puro  propongo  empleando `JQuery`.  Se puede lograr esto haciendo uso de `focus()` cuando el foco está activo y `blur` cuando el foco no lo está.

Estos eventos se les añadirán al elemento `window` que es nuestra ventana del navegador. para saber el tiempo tendríamos una variable contadora, cada vez que tenga el evento `focus` cuente 1 segundo haciendo uso de `setInterval` y cuando no , limpiamos el `interval` con `clearInterval`.

```js
$(function() {
  var i = 0;
  var intervalo;
  $(window).focus(function() {
      intervalo = setInterval(function(){
          i++;
         console.log(i);
       },1000);
   }).blur(function() {
      clearInterval(intervalo);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar los eventos focus y blur del objeto window:

```js
$(function(){
  var cont = 0;
  var inactiveTime = null;
  var interval;

  function init(){
    inactiveTime = new Date();
    interval = setInterval(refresh, 500);
  }
  
  function refresh(){
    if (inactiveTime != null) {
      var currentTime = new Date();
      var secondsPartial = Math.floor((currentTime.getTime() - inactiveTime.getTime()) / 1000);
      $('#inactivo').text(secondsPartial);
      $('#inactivoTotal').text(secondsPartial + cont);
    }
  }
    
  window.addEventListener('focus', function(){
    refresh();
    clearInterval(interval);
    inactiveTime = null;
    cont = parseInt($('#inactivoTotal').text() | 0);
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('blur', init);
  
  init();
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Tiempo inactivo total: <span id="inactivoTotal"></span>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
Tiempo inactivo: <span id="inactivo"></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

cuando puerde el foco se ejecuta onblur, asi que obtienes una variable que te marque cuando perdio el foco

```
var fuera;
window.onblur = function() { fuera=Date.now(); }
```

cuando regresa calculas el tiempo que estuvo fuera de foco.

```
window.onfocus=function() { console.log(Date.now()-fuera); }
```