# Como saber si la pestana esta activa?

Tags: javascript, navegador-web

Como puedo detectar en el navegador si el usuario tiene la pestana (o tab) activa?. Hay alguna forma? Digamos que quiera loguear en la consola cada vez que abandona la pestana solo para saber.

Comment: Esta pregunta te puede ser de ayuda: [¿Cómo puedo saber el tiempo activo de la web?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/80285/250)

Answer (score 2):

Ayudandome del link proporcionado por Montoro y de aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/visibilitychange, lo que mas util me ha sido es anyadir un event listener por "visibilitychange". De esta forma quedaria asi:

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log( document.visibilityState );
});
```

Comment: ya te puse como hacerlo

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo si tienes una pagina que reproduce música cuando tienes la ventana activa y cuando no, para creas una función que reproduce la música en dependencia del valor del parámetro, esto seria un ejemplo con los eventos que se disparan en ambas acciones

```
<body onFocus="Musica_suena(true)" onBlur="Musica_suena(false)">
```